# jQuery validation form getting refreshed

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am validating from with jQuery validation plugin and facing some issues with my validation code.

If I click to `Save` button validation error messages appears which is perfect but If I select to radio button and hit the submit button page getting refreshed and that is going to wrong for me.

Any Idea why page is refreshing and what I am doing wrong?

Here is my JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mananpatel/qp8nm27t/

### Html structure:

```
<form name="FrmEditAccountDetails" id="FrmEditAccountDetails" method="post" action="#">
    <div class="box box-default">
        <div class="box-header">
            <h3 class="box-title">Payment Details</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">* Please select your prefered payment option</label>
                <span class="has-error"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="radio bank_div">
                    <label for="pd_bank_payment_option">
                        <input type="radio" name="pd_payment_option" id="pd_bank_payment_option" class="pd_bank_payment_option" value="bank">Bank details
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio paypal_div">
                    <label for="pd_paypan_payment_option">
                        <input type="radio" name="pd_payment_option" id="pd_paypan_payment_option" class="pd_bank_payment_option" value="paypal">Paypal email
                    </label>
                </div>
                <span class="has-error"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group frm-grp1">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pd_account_holder_name">Account Holder Name *</label>
                    <input type="text" name="pd_account_holder_name" value="" id="pd_account_holder_name" class="form-control" maxlength="50">
                    <span class="has-error"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pd_iban">IBAN *</label>
                    <input type="text" name="pd_iban" value="" id="pd_iban" class="form-control" maxlength="50">
                    <span class="has-error"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pd_bic_code">BIC code</label>
                    <input type="text" name="pd_bic_code" value="" id="pd_bic_code" class="form-control" maxlength="50">
                    <span class="has-error"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pd_bank_name">Bank name *</label>
                    <input type="text" name="pd_bank_name" value="" id="pd_bank_name" class="form-control" maxlength="50">
                    <span class="has-error"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group frm-grp2 none">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pd_paypal_email">Paypal email *</label>
                    <input type="text" name="pd_paypal_email" value="" id="pd_paypal_email" class="form-control" maxlength="50">
                    <span class="has-error"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn bg-orange btn-flat save-account-details">Save</button>&nbsp;
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

### jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Code for show/hide divs
        $(document.body).on('click', '.pd_bank_payment_option', function() {
            if(this.value == "bank"){
                $('.frm-grp2').hide();
                $('.frm-grp1').show();

                $("#pd_paypal_email").prop('disabled', true);
                $("#pd_account_holder_name").prop('disabled', false);
                $("#pd_iban").prop('disabled', false);
                $("#pd_bic_code").prop('disabled', false);
                $("#pd_bank_name").prop('disabled', false);
                $('#FrmEditAccountDetails').valid();
            }else{
                $('.frm-grp2').show();
                $('.frm-grp1').hide();

                $("#pd_account_holder_name").prop('disabled', true);
                $("#pd_iban").prop('disabled', true);
                $("#pd_bic_code").prop('disabled', true);
                $("#pd_bank_name").prop('disabled', true);
                $("#pd_paypal_email").prop('disabled', false);
                $('#FrmEditAccountDetails').valid();
            }
        });

        // Code for form validation
        $(document.body).on('click', '#FrmEditAccountDetails .save-account-details', function() {
            if ($("#FrmEditAccountDetails").length) {
                $("#FrmEditAccountDetails").validate({
                    onkeyup: false,
                    onfocusout: false,
                    errorElement: 'span',
                    // errorClass: 'has-error',
                    ignore: [],
                    rules: {
                        "pd_payment_option": {
                            required: true
                        },
                        "pd_account_holder_name": {
                            required: true
                        },
                        "pd_iban": {
                            required: true
                        },
                        "pd_bic_code": {
                            required: false
                        },
                        "pd_bank_name": {
                            required: true
                        },
                        "pd_paypal_email": {
                            required: false,
                            required: function(element) {
                                return $("input[name='pd_payment_option']:checked").val() == 'paypal';
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    messages: {
                        "pd_payment_option": {
                            required: "Please select your Payment Option."
                        },
                        "pd_account_holder_name": {
                            required: "Please enter your Account Holder Name."
                        },
                        "pd_iban": {
                            required: "Please enter your IBAN."
                        },
                        "pd_bic_code": {
                            required: "Please enter your BIC Code."
                        },
                        "pd_bank_name": {
                            required: "Please enter your Bank Name."
                        },
                        "pd_paypal_email": {
                            required: "Please enter your Paypal Email Address."
                        }
                    },
                    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                        error.insertAfter(element);
                    },
                    onfocusout: function(element, event) {
                        if (!this.checkable(element) && (element.name in this.submitted || !this.optional(element))) {
                            this.element(element);
                        }
                    },
                    submitHandler: function() {
                        alert('form is valid');
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can setup the validation on document.ready, and that will solve part of your problem.  Change this:

```
    $(document.body).on('click', '#FrmEditAccountDetails .save-account-details', function() {
```

To this:

```
    $(document.body).ready(function() {
```

Also, you don't need to set the required:false and also set it to a function for your `pd_paypal_email`:

```
                    "pd_paypal_email": {
                        required: function(element) {
                            return $("input[name='pd_payment_option']:checked").val() == 'paypal';
                        }
```

That's it!

Working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/qp8nm27t/3/

Answer (score -1):

You need to do `e.preventDefault();`
If you don't use `e.preventDefault()`, the default behaviour of form submit will fire. It will send browser to the action property of form and browser will disappeared that you don't want it.

```
      $(document.body).on('click', '#FrmEditAccountDetails .save-account-details', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($("#FrmEditAccountDetails").length) {
            $("#FrmEditAccountDetails").validate({
                onkeyup: false,
                onfocusout: false,
                errorElement: 'span',
                // errorClass: 'has-err
```

Comment: Thanks for guidance but can you explain me how to do with my code as I am leaning jQuery.

Comment: I don't have any submit event in my code. I am validating form using click event.

Comment: where you listen for the onClick or onSubmit event in jquery you need to prevent the default behavior

Comment: I have tried by adding `e.preventDefault();` but can you please try with my fiddle because it is not working properly when adding `e.preventDefault();`. Thanks.

Comment: your entire form is in `<form></form>` and the `type=submit` triggers the default operation do this `$(document.body).on('submit', '#FrmEditAccountDetails .save-account-details', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95170/discussion-between-varun-tewari-and-php-baby).